# date/time dropdownlist that is restricted to specific times and dates

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I was wondering if there were any ways out there to create a dropdownlist in asp .net that would have date/time picker or just a specific list of dates and times in the list?

Comment: [How to ask a question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Ajax toolkit - Calender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx) . I think its what you need. I'm not sure if it has time though.

Comment: I believe this should work perfectly!